# "Get punished" and "be punished"

Tags: difference, passive-voice

What is the difference between these two?

> They will be punished.
>
> They will get punished.

Comment: How are yo messed up about them? Please write more so we can answer appropriately.

Comment: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/get-passive